# Kafka Streams: Appropriate way to find min value in a stream

Tags: apache-kafka, apache-kafka-streams

I'm using Kafka Streams version 0.10.0.1, and trying to find the min value in a stream.

The incoming messages come from a topic called kafka-streams-topic and have a key and the value is a JSON payload that looks like this:

```
{"value":2334}
```

This is a simple payload but I want to find the min value of this JSON.

The outgoing message is just a number:
2334

and the key is also part of the message.

So if the incoming topic got:

```
key=1, value={"value":1000}
```

outgoing topic, named min-topic, would get

```
key=1,value=1000
```

another message comes through:

```
key=1, value={"value":100}
```

because this is the same key I would like to now produce a message with key=1 value=100 since this is now smaller than the first message

Now lets say we got:

```
key=2 value=99
```

A new message would be produced where:

```
key=2 and value=99 but the key=1 and associated value shouldn't change.
```

Additionally if we got the message:

```
key=1 value=2000
```

No message should be produced since this message is larger than the current value of 100

This works but I'm wondering if this adheres to the intent of the API:

```java
public class MinProcessor implements Processor<String,String> {

    private ProcessorContext context;
    private KeyValueStore<String, Long> kvStore;
    private Gson gson = new Gson();

    @Override
    public void init(ProcessorContext context) {
        this.context = context;
        this.context.schedule(1000);
        kvStore = (KeyValueStore) context.getStateStore("Counts");
    }

    @Override
    public void process(String key, String value) {
        Long incomingPotentialMin = ((Double)gson.fromJson(value, Map.class).get("value")).longValue();
        Long minForKey = kvStore.get(key);
        System.out.printf("key: %s incomingPotentialMin: %s minForKey: %s \n", key, incomingPotentialMin, minForKey);

        if (minForKey == null || incomingPotentialMin < minForKey) {
            kvStore.put(key, incomingPotentialMin);
            context.forward(key, incomingPotentialMin.toString());
            context.commit();
        }
    }

    @Override
    public void punctuate(long timestamp) {}

    @Override
    public void close() {
        kvStore.close();
    }
}
```

Here is the code that actually runs the processor:

```java
public class MinLauncher {

    public static void main(String[] args) {    
        TopologyBuilder builder = new TopologyBuilder();

        StateStoreSupplier countStore = Stores.create("Counts")
                .withKeys(Serdes.String())
                .withValues(Serdes.Long())
                .persistent()
                .build();

        builder.addSource("source", "kafka-streams-topic")
                .addProcessor("process", () -> new MinProcessor(), "source")
                .addStateStore(countStore, "process")
                .addSink("sink", "min-topic", "process");

        KafkaStreams streams = new KafkaStreams(builder, KafkaStreamsProperties.properties("kafka-streams-min-poc"));
        streams.cleanUp();
        streams.start();

        Runtime.getRuntime().addShutdownHook(new Thread(streams::close));
    }
}
```

Answer (score 2):

Not sure what your exact input data and result is (maybe you can update you question with this information: what are your input records? what is your output? What *"EXTRA messages [] are produced [] that [you] don't expect"*?).

However, a few general clarifications (can refine this answer later on if required).

- You do your computation based in keys, so you should expect a result for each key (not sure if you have multiple different keys in your input).
- You emit data in `punctuate()` which is called periodically (base in the internally tracked stream-time -- i.e., based on the timestamp values extracted from your input records via `TimestampExtractor`). Hence, you will write the ***current*** min value of each key written to the topic when `punctuate()` gets called and therefore, you can have multiple updates per key that are all appended to your result topic. (Topics are append only and if you write two messages with the same key, you see both -- there is no overwrite.)